# Не работает сайт на веб сервере

Tags: php, apache

Здравствуйте! Есть сайт, который нормально работает на локальным сервере. Когда заливаю на веб сервер, вылезает куча ошибок. Сначала ругался что не видит файлы подключенные через `require ...`, когда поменял `require` на `include` все более или менее заработало. Теперь такое ощущение что не видит вообще файлы с функциями. Версия `php` на локальном сервере и на веб сервере `5.6`. В чем может быть проблема? Почему на локальном сервере работает, на на веб уже нет? P.S. Как можно проверить правильно ли я указал путь ко всем файлам?

Comment: Покажите логи апача. Они должны быть доступны в панели управления или в файле /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: И еще скажите на чем сайт построен?

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan, php 5.6, локальный сервер apache 2.4, если вы это имели ввиду

Answer (score 0):

Основные ошибки начинающих программистов, при первой заливке PHP файлов на хостинг.

1. Регистр. На Windows он был не важен, строка:
   `include'File.php';`
   успешно найдет файл с названием "FiLe.Php".
   Но на *nix хостинге файл будет не найден.
2. Разница версий, на хостингах редко появляются новые версии PHP.
3. Разница настроек. Например могут отключить "exec", "mail".
4. Модули, локально подключено как правило много всего "на всякий случай".
   На хостинге подключены далеко не все.
5. Кодировка. Всегда используйте UTF-8, иначе есть вероятность получить "иероглифы" или пустую страницу.

P.S.: Вывод ошибок на хостинге, как правило выключен в целях безопасности. Можно включить его, либо начать пользоваться логами.

Comment: и к чему эти общие советы? тут полезного применительно к данному вопросу только в п.1.

Comment: В вопросе нет никаких подробностей об ошибках. Общий вопрос - общие советы.

Comment: дак у человека проблема с путями и инклудами. при чем тут mail  и остальное?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, смена require на include не поможет, поэтому у вас и не работают некоторые функции, так как include от require отличается в том, что require падает в Fatal error при невозможности подключения файла по любой причине. А include только выдает Warning и спокойно продолжает работу.

Что касается проблем на сервере, прежде всего вам нужно прописать в каком либо файле:

```
phpinfo();
```

И проверить информацию о текущем состоянии PHP. По моему мнению проблему будет именно в этом. Также хороший вариант написать тикет вашему хост-провайдреу, объяснить вашу проблему, и в большинстве случаев они подсказывают, что не так.